# Why Selenium webdriver is not maximize chrome on remote machine?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run tests on my local machine it's working but the remote machine is not maximized chrome. Because of this driver cant find the elements on the screen, all tests failed. I have tried all recommended solutions. Here is my code.

public class BrowserFactory extends BaseTest {

```
public WebDriver prepareDriver() {
    WebDriver driver;

    if (getAveaConfiguration().isRemote().booleanValue()) {
        driver = getRemoteDriver();
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(1936,1056);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
        System.out.println("PageSize:" + driver.manage().window().getSize());
    } else {
        driver = getLocalDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
    }
    return driver;
}

private WebDriver getRemoteDriver() {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    DesiredCapabilities cap = getRemoteCapabilities();
    try {
        System.out.println(getAveaConfiguration().getGridURL());
        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(getAveaConfiguration().getGridURL()), cap);

        ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        throw new TestException(mue);
    }
    return webDriver;
}

private DesiredCapabilities getRemoteCapabilities() {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    if ("firefox".equals(getAveaConfiguration().getBrowser())) {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);

        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        return capabilities;

    } else if ("ie".equals(getAveaConfiguration().getBrowser())) {
        return DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

    } else {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        options.addArguments("enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.addArguments("enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        return capabilities;
    }
}

private WebDriver getLocalDriver() {
    switch (getAveaConfiguration().getBrowser()) {
    case "chrome":
        return new ChromeDriver();
```

//          case "ie":
//              return new InternetExplorerDriver(getCapabilitiesForIe());
default:
return new ChromeDriver();
}
}

Comment: maybe try to scroll the element into view instead?
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);

Comment: Actually, my problem is the page size of chrome. Its have to be maximized to be able to find all elements. Scrolling just solves one step. Here is my SS of the problem. Page loading like this. https://prnt.sc/26ed7x5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem but forget to close my question. The problem is google chrome files moved to another path by someone. Install the chrome again and problem solved.